# Django admin site not showing CSS style

Tags: django, apache

My Django admin website (it's completely default, not customized) is not showing the expected CSS.

It looks like this:

[image]

And I can log in:

[image]

But it is supposed to look like this:

[image]

How do I fix this?

**Other info that might help:**

I'm running on an Amazon EC2 instance on port 80 and connecting to it using a real URL. I set it up using this tutorial:
http://www.nickpolet.com/blog/deploying-django-on-aws/1/

Following that tutorial, I put this code into a file called `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.conf`. I don't understand what this code is doing, so I think it might be related to the problem.

**/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.conf:**

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/cs462/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/ubuntu/cs462/mysite
<Directory /home/ubuntu/cs462/mysite/mysite>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Order deny,allow
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

Alias /media/ /home/ubuntu/cs462/mysite/media/
Alias /static/ /home/ubuntu/cs462/mysite/static/

<Directory /home/ubuntu/cs462/mysite/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/ubuntu/cs462/mysite/media>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**Directory structure:**

```
/home/ubuntu/cs462/
        mysite/
            manage.py
            db.sqlite3
            mysite/
                __init__.py
                __init__.pyc  
                settings.py  
                settings.pyc  
                urls.py  
                wsgi.py
            homepage/
                admin.py  
                admin.pyc  
                __init__.py  
                __init__.pyc  
                migrations  
                models.py  
                models.pyc  
                tests.py  
                views.py
```

**Last part of settings.py:**

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your Apache configuration requires that all static content (CSS, JS, images etc) should be in the mysite/static directory. You should collect your static content from apps into the mysite/static directory first:

```
cd /home/ubuntu/cs462/mysite
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Update: If you did not specify a location for static content, you should add the following lines to your `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Comment: What do you mean? I don't have any static content. This is just the admin site that comes with Django. I only created a superuser to log in to the admin site, and it has my tables from the database from my models.py file.

Comment: Django admin app has its own static content installed. You should copy them to your project's static directory first. You don't recognize it while testing the site using the Django's built-in development server but for production you need to run collectstatic first.

Comment: Great! It worked. I made the change in settings.py, and then I needed to re-run the `python manage.py collectstatic` command. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Keep DEBUG=False

Run

pip install whitenoise

IN settings.py

add INSTALLED_APPS

```
'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
```

Add like below in MIDDLEWARE:

```
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',  # add it exactly here
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
```

Don't Change below statements:

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

Comment: Works for cPanel deployments

Answer (score 0):

after doing

1. python manage.py collectstatic
2. In settings.py, in STATICFILES_DIRS variable, append

('admin', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'admin')). This should work