# Django : no CSS on Admin page

Tags: python, django

After reading some tutorials and questions on SO (for example : [css not loading in my login and admin page in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30071257/css-not-loading-in-my-login-and-admin-page-in-django)), I don't find a way to load css stylesheet.

It comes from migration between my MacOSX localhost machine and my new Ubuntu distant server.

My **admin login page** looks like :

[image]

As you can see, I don't have CSS which is taken account from `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/`

All my admin part looks like this : without CSS

I have a **settings.py** file which looks like :

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app1',
    'app2',
    'app3',
    'app4',
    'app5',
    'django_countries',
    'app6',
    'app7',

]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['/var/www/html/myproject/templates/',
                 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/',
                 '/var/www/html/myproject/app1/templates/',
                 '/var/www/html/myproject/app2/templates/',
                 '/var/www/html/myproject/app3/templates/' ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug' : DEBUG,
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "/var/www/html/myproject/static/"),)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# SESSION AGE 100 Minutes
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 100*60 # X * 60s

# Simple Math
CAPTCHA_CHALLENGE_FUNCT = 'captcha.helpers.math_challenge'
```

So I don't find a way to get this kind of template :

[image]

If you have advices which could help me ?

Thank you by advance !

**EDIT :**

**Traceback from `python manage.py collectstatic`**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 193, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 114, in collect
    for finder in get_finders():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 264, in get_finders
    yield get_finder(finder_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py", line 100, in wrapper
    result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 277, in get_finder
    return Finder()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 66, in __init__
    "The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting
```

**Part of Apache2.conf :**

```
Alias /static/ /var/www/html/myproject/static/

<Directory /var/www/html/myproject/static/>
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/myproject


<Directory /var/www/html/myproject/myproject>
        <Files wsgi.py>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
        SetEnvIfNoCase Host .+ VALID_HOST
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from All
        Allow from env=VALID_HOST
        </Files>
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#       AllowOverride None
#       Require all granted
#</Directory>

LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so

<VirtualHost *:80>
  Alias /media/ /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py collectstatic` on your new server?

Comment: Is this with DEBUG true or false? Are you using runserver or Apache/nginx/what? Have you set up your server to serve static files and if so how?

Comment: I added Traceback from `python manage.py collectstatic` that I've already tried

Comment: @DanielRoseman Debug is True, I'm using Apache with mod_wsgi. I edited my question with apache2.conf file

Comment: So, did you try setting STATIC_ROOT to something that is not contained by STATICFILES_DIRS?

Comment: And as all tracebacks, it ends with the error message. Which part of it did you not understand?

Comment: @DanielRoseman No I don't try this kind of things. As I'm beginning, I have to learn what's the difference between STATICFILES_DIRS and STATIC_ROOT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run the collect static command we need to set STATIC_ROOT where out collectstatic output files will be stored so add STATIC_ROOT in your settings file and make sure the STATIC_ROOT path served from your apache conf.
In your settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    )
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

so when you run collectstatic all the files will be collected you staticfiles directory.

And update `Alias /static/` to

```
Alias /static/ /var/www/html/myproject/staticfiles/
```

for more about static file serving check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

Comment: It is `staticfiles` directory.