# Getting django database admin pages with no css

Tags: django

I'm getting the django admin page with no css.  I changed static url and re-install both python and pycharm. But still getting it without any css. I'm using windows 10 os.

Comment: Run python3 manage.py collectstatic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django : no CSS on Admin page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42005205/django-no-css-on-admin-page)