# Django 1.9 admin not showing CSS style

Tags: css, django

I am new to `django` and currently I am making the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/). It goes well but every time at some point my admin site loses ist CSS styling and starts looking like this:
[image]

This problem is apparently not new, as I found few posts here (e.g., [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28728912/django-admin-site-not-showing-css-style) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420378/why-my-django-admin-site-does-not-have-the-css-style)) on the topic. Following the answers I made the next steps:

1. Running `python manage.py collectstatic`
2. Modifying `settings.py`:

   `STATIC_URL = '/static/'
   STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`
3. Adding the following lines to `manage.py`:

   `import mimetypes
   mimetypes.init()
   mimetypes.types_map['.css'] = 'text/css'`
4. Going sure that `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` in `settings.py` is uncommented.

Nevertheless, nothing worked and my admin site still does not have CSS styling.

Note that in my case the problem is not consistent. Whenever I start a new project, the admin page is fine. The problem appears only after certain (and each time different) step throughout the tutorial. For example, last time it was after I modified the `DATABASES` entry in `settings.py` (though I went through this step smoothly one attempt before; changing the entry to its original value did not help to restore the admin page styling).

I am using `django 1.9.6` with `python 3.4.3` under `Ubuntu 14.04`.

**EDIT:**

I am running server with `#DEBUG = True` and `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`

Comment: could you possibly post the <head> section of the Django admin index page?

Comment: @ techydesigner: DEBUG is not true. Where do I find the admin index page?

Comment: Try activating DEBUG to true.

Comment: @Roman Nevermind about the admin index page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django does not serve any static or media files when `DEBUG = False`.

Changing the variable to `True` and the static files for the admin site will appear. Otherwise, you will have to use a web server program to server the admin files as well as any other static/media files included in your project.

Comment: Lots of similar questions about this on SO, but this was the only one that helped me - thanks!