# CSS is not loading in Django Admin Panel App?

Tags: python, css, django

I have created my first Django project, but in the admin panel, when I run `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/` the **CSS** files is not loaded and I also created a new Django app but still got the same error, I have also visited the question but my problem is not solved: [Django admin site not showing CSS style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28728912/django-admin-site-not-showing-css-style/28728935)

**It looks like this:**

[image: Django Admin Login]

I can log in:

[image: Django Admin Dashboard]

It should look like this:

[image: Django Admin Login with CSS]
[image: Django Admin Dashboard with CSS]

**settings.py**

```
import os

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('products/', include('products.urls'))
]
```

**Note**: I have used `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')` in **settings.py** and also run the command `python manage.py collectstatic`, but still, I got the same thing.

Comment: If you in development `./manage.py runserver`, did you use ` + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` in `urls.py` as in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development ?

Comment: maybe `python manage.py collectstatic` will help

Comment: @sunil ghimire I have used that but it didn't help me

Comment: Show your project urls.py file code you need to import `django settings` there  and define static files query!

Comment: @Gasanov I applied static in `urls.py` but it is still the same

Comment: @HedayatullahSarwary Are u running it locally or deployed it somewhere like aws

Comment: @Blackranger I run this locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Guys I added the following in my `setting.py` file, and now it's working fine:

```
import mimetypes
mimetypes.add_type("text/css", ".css", True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `DEBUG=False` in `settings.py`, you need to manually serve static files. Note that this is **not recommended** for production - you should serve static files using your web server such as apache on nginx. Also note that django will do this automatically, if you have `DEBUG=True`.

urls.py:

```
import re

from django.urls import re_path
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.static import serve

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    re_path(r'^%s(?P<path>.*)$' % re.escape(settings.STATIC_URL.lstrip('/')), serve, {"document_root": settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
]
```

Comment: Not working, I have used your code, it didn't help me.

Comment: @HedayatullahSarwary But is your `DEBUG=False`?

Comment: When I turn `DEBUG=False`, `python manage.py runserver` stops?

Answer (score 0):

try this might help

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.static import serve
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings


    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

or if it still does not work for you
set debug=false
thane python manage.py collectstatic after creating a static cdn folder and paste you localhost path in allowed host section and then tell us if it still not loading admin css

Comment: and please also try to remove all your cache from browser